# How to implement a click event on textbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

In my web application I need a functionality so that when users click on textbox to input values, it should make the button and the other fields visible?

I am using the code provided below but, could not get it working.

C#:

```
protected void TextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonSearch.Visible = true;
}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" OnClick="TextBox1_Click"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" Text="Search" Visible="False" />
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `AutoPostback="True"`. This way the event will be fired server-side, and the button will become visible.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"     OnClick="TextBox1_Click" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, if you only want to toogle visility of a button, you really should considerate javascript. This will save a trip back to the server.

```
<asp:TextBox onclick="txtBox1_ClientClicked()" ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnClick="TextBox1_Click"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" Text="Search" style="display:none;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function txtBox1_ClientClicked(){
        var theButton = document.getElementById('<%=ButtonSearch.ClientID%>');
        theButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the perfect solution for your problem. The code would be something like this:

```
$("#TextBox1").on("click",function(){$("#ButtonSearch").css("visibility", "visible");})
```

You include the script by adding `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the page and then you can add the piece of code above to within `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: This question looks so silly but, I have never used jquery before.where should I add this portion of code?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to post back to the server to accomplish your job. You can use client side `onFocus` event and javascript/jquery, for example.

I know I used an input of type text, and you are using an ASP Control which posts on server, but here is a JSFiddle to get you on the right track: http://jsfiddle.net/Mmjtz/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<%= ButtonSearch.ClientID %>").click(function(){
$("#TextBox1").show():
});
```

In this code you need to pass fields ID which you want to visible on the click of button.

Answer (score 0):

Put the textbox inside a `div` and use the `div`'s `onClick` event from codebehind. It's not what you asked but it works for me without any errors. Here is a `javascript` function to implement requested event:

```
function toggleVisibility() 
{
document.getElementById('TextBox1').disabled = true;
            /*
            ...some other code...
            */
}
```

And of course, you have to define your `onclick` event at the `div` definition after implementing this JS function.

```
<div id="TBdiv" onClick="toggleVisibility()">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"..../>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT:** Since you now disabled your `TextBox` from codebehind, you have to enable it in somewhere before you want to use it again. Otherwise you will not see it while the page is running.