# How to change visibility of Calendar on textbox click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I want to use `TextBox` and `Calendar` to make a date selection field as given below,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date_selected" Enabled="false" CssClass="date" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="image_calendar" runat="server" Width="32px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" Height="32px" ImageUrl="/Images/calendar.png" OnClick="image_calendar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
<asp:Calendar ID="calendar" Visible="false" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="calendar_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

Here as i click the `ImageButton` the `Calendar` will become visible and after i click on a date the `TextBox` will be filled with that date using script below,

```
protected void image_calendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    calendar.Visible = true;
}

protected void calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    date_selected.Text = calendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString().ToString();
    calendar.Visible = false;
}
```

But i want to do this without using an `ImageButton` and as i click on the `TextBox` itself the `Calendar` should be displayed. But `TextBox` doesnt have any `OnClick` function to it. Is there any other way to do this using `TextBox:focus` in `CSS` or by using `JavaScript` or `JQuery`?

In `CSS` i know we can hide visibility of an item using the properties `display: none` and 'visibility: hidden` but is there any way to do it as below?

```
#date_selected:focus {
    // set visibility of Calendar to "visible"
}
```

**FINAL CODE (EDIT)**

Below is the final code i am using.

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date_selected" ReadOnly="true" MaxLength="10" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Calendar ID="calendar" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="calendar_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

**C#**

```
protected void calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    date_selected.Text = calendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString().ToString();
    calendar.Visible = false;
}
```

**CSS**

```
#calendar {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index : 9999 !important;
}

#date_selected:focus ~ #calendar {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But after the calendar is displayed even if i click on any date its not getting updated in the text box? im not sure why? Not just on any date, the calendar disappear if i click anywhere on the calendar i cant even change the month. Maybe when i click somewhere on the calendar the focus on textbox is gone and calendar is gone. How can i solve this?

Comment: are you looking for something like this : `$('#date_selected').focus(function() { $('#Calendar ').show(); });`

Comment: I think so..Im not well aware of JQuery i will try this script

Comment: it wont work should i add any JQuery links or something in header?

Comment: yes, you should add
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`  or  `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>` in your header

Comment: its not working..can i do it any other way? maybe in C# or something?

Comment: using css, try to use `~` selector.
`#date_selected:focus ~ #calendar{
    // set visibility of Calendar to "visible"
}`

Comment: Oh thank you the `Selector` is working but i have another problem can u look into my **EDIT** in the question

Comment: [How to implement click event on textbox in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620935/how-to-implement-click-event-on-textbox-in-asp-net) Have a look, may be helpful ?

Comment: OnClick event is not working in TextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to put it above other div, you could use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
#date_selected:focus ~ #calendar {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index : 9999 !important;
}
```

Also, by using `Jquery`, you should put it inside `document ready` function to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#date_selected').focus(function() { $('#Calendar ').show(); });
});
```

If you want to add a calendar function, you can also use [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Its a nice, simple and easy to be used plugin in Jquery. By using `datepicker` you dont have to set the css and calendar anymore. Then you will use it just like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#date_selected').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the `z-index` is working..but still when i click any date its not getting updated in textbox, i edited my question please check it out..I did add the `OnSelctionChanged` to the calendar

Comment: @ManoUncharted best suggestion for you, is using datepicker function. its an easy use jquery plugin

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#date_selected').datepicker();
        }
    </script>` should i add like this?

Comment: @ManoUncharted sorry im not sure about framework 2.0, but you could try it. yes, but i just edit the closing, forgot to add `);`

Comment: is it possible to download datepicker files instead of linking to web? i can download and link to the files in my system right? where can i download them?

Comment: if i add these headers, i need internet connection to use them right? or not?

Comment: yes you need an internet connection. you can download it here. https://plugins.jquery.com/ui.datepicker/

Comment: ok thanks..but it has a problem..im using autopostback for my date textbox ..it wont work well the datapicker..after i select the date for first time it works..then when i click textbox again it wont work..It works if i remove autopostback. I need to use autopostback to check if date is entered or not..if entered then a label field should be updated with the date. If not selected it should be update as no date selected

Comment: @ManoUncharted you could refer to here : https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1728

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above simply by using `Ajax Toolkit`,try the below one

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID="txtDate" >
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: it says the CalendarExtender tag is not found..is there any other way without using external toolkit or libraries?